# Python & Strings/Loops help please

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to make a name that is inputted in:

```
full_name = input('Enter your full name ')
```

Be changed to be completely backwards through the use of a while loop.

For example: Make `Jenny King` to `gniK ynneJ`

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a great book, honestly. Why use a while loop to reverse a string when you can use slicing or `reversed`? Why use slicing to split the string into first and last names when you can use `split`? If you're having a hard time, it might just be because they're making you do assignments in a roundabout way.

Comment: As I am reading through my book, I was wondering why they are using a while loop for that as well, and it does not explain anywhere how to use a while loop in that manner...

Comment: @Kevin I'm more worried because of the "Assign ... to a string". Maybe it's not a Python book.

Comment: @Kevin it could be that the author is going through 'how other languages do it' and then 'look how much easier it is to do in Python'? Which is probably not the most efficient style, but hey, I didn't write the book either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Using while loop

```
i = len(full_name.split()) - 1
while(i >= 0):
    print full_name.split()[i]
    i = i-1
```

2- Slicing

```
x = full_name.index(" ")
new_string = full_name[x+1:] + " " + full_name[0:x]
print new_string
```

3- Counting lower and upper

```
lower = 0
upper = 0
for letter in full_name:
    if letter.islower():
        lower = lower + 1
    elif letter.isupper():
        upper = upper + 1
print "number of lower letters = %s" % lower 
print "number of upper letters = %s" % upper
```

4- correcting the sentence

```
bad_string = "You have to be vewy, vewy twicky to twap a wascally wabbit"
correct_string = bad_string.replace('w', 'r')
print correct_string
```

Comment: @JennyKing, if you have a refinement to make to the question, please edit the question and not someone else's attempt to answer your question. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. Did not mean to. New to this.